# Theoretical question about continuity

Tags: functions, derivatives, continuity, partial-derivative

I am supposed to determine if following statement is true:

> Let $f\left ( x,y \right )$ be the function of two variables defined
>   on neighbourhood $\left ( 0,0 \right )\subseteq \mathbb{R}^{2}$. If
>   there exist a partial derivation of function f in point $\left ( 0,0
>  \right )$, then the function is continous in point $\left ( 0,0 \right
>  )$.

In my opinion yes, because it can be differentiable only if partial derivation of the function are continous, so it must be continous in point  $\left ( 0,0 \right
 )$.

Is that true?

Comment: Try $f(x,y) = \dfrac{xy}{x^2 + y^2}$ where $f(0,0) = 0$

Comment: Or, more extreme, $f(x,y)=1$ if at least one of $x,y$ is rational and 0 otherwise.

Comment: @sat091 thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $f(x,y)=\frac {xy} {x^{2}+y^{2}}$ for  $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$ and $f(0,0)=0$ then $f$ has partial derivatives at $(0,0)$ but it is not continuous at $(0,0)$.

Comment: Thank you so much